# Solving the system $ax + by = 1$, $cx + dy = 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From Serge Lang's book:

> Let $a, $b, $c, $d be numbers such that $ ad - bc \neq 0 $. Solve the following systems of equations for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a, $b, $c, $d.
>
> $$
> \begin{cases}
> ax + by = 1 \\
> cx + dy = 2  
> \end{cases}
> $$

What I did so far step by step

\begin{cases}
ax + by = 1 \\
cx + dy = 2 
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
cax + cby = c  \\
cax + ady = 2a 
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
cax = c - cby  \\
cax + ady = 2a 
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
cax = c - cby  \\
c - cby + ady = 2a 
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
cax = c - cby  \\
y(ad - cb) = 2a - c
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
cax = c - cby  \\
y = \dfrac{2a - c}{ad-cb}
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
x = \dfrac{c - cby}{ca}   \\
y = \dfrac{2a - c}{ad-cb}
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
x = \dfrac{c(1 - by)}{ca}   \\
y = \dfrac{2a - c}{ad-cb}
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
x = \dfrac{1 - by}{a}   \\
y = \dfrac{2a - c}{ad-cb}
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
x =  \dfrac{1 - b * \dfrac{2a - c}{ad-cb}}{a}  \\
y = \dfrac{2a - c}{ad-cb}
\end{cases}

Book's solution says that

> $x=\dfrac{d -2b}{ad - bc}$

but after multiple tries I can't get my equation to a point where $x$ looks near like the desired answer. Could someone hint me where I did a mistake in my thought process or what I am doing wrong in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Doug M points out, your expression has the right value *if it is defined*. However it involves dividing by $a$, and you don't have any reason to assume that $a\ne 0$. In fact, something starts going wrong at the point in your derivation where you divide an equation by $ac$.

You have a correct and relatively direct derivation of $y=\frac{2a-c}{ac-bd}$. What you *ought to* have done when you've reached that is to go back to the *original* equations and isolate $x$ in the same way: multiply one equation by $d$, the other by $b$, and subtract.

It looks like you've gotten yourself tied into a knot by attempting to make all your rewritings of the system work with $\Leftrightarrow$ instead of merely $\Rightarrow$. That's *generally* a useful strategy, but it's not a divine command. In this case the noble intention doesn't even work for you, because you *might* be multiplying by zero right at the beginning when you multiply equations by $a$ and $c$, and then you only get $\Rightarrow$ anyway. Since you have to risk destroying information to get anything done, you might as well derive expressions for $x$ and $y$ separately, which will tell you that *if* the system has a solution, *these* values must be the ones. Then check that they indeed work by inserting them in the original equation and simplifying.

Comment: Thank you! It explained quite a lot to me and I was able to progress with the exercise :) By accident I also evaluated the system to $x = \dfrac{2b - d}{cb - ad} and it got me thinking if a statement ad - bc \neq 0 also implies that bc - ad \neq 0? If we move the variables at the right sight of the equation then it will be equal to bc - ad and the above will be true or am I missing something?

Comment: @KarolGruszka: Yes, since $ad-bc$ and $bc-ad$ are minus each other, they are either both nonzero or both zero.

Answer (score 1):

What you have so far is fine.  You just need to simplify $x$

$x =  \dfrac{1 - b * \dfrac{2a - c}{ad-cb}}{a}\\
 \dfrac{\left(1 - b * \dfrac{2a - c}{ad-cb}\right)(ad-cb)}{a(ad-cb)}\\
\dfrac{ad-cb - 2ab + cb}{a(ad-cb)}\\
\dfrac{a(d - 2b)}{a(ad-cb)}\\
\dfrac{d - 2b}{ad-cb}$

Comment: Thanks! Damn, I'd probably never figure out to multiply it the way you did. Nice trick :)

Comment: It is pretty standard to remove fractions within fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't downvote or close this, because I think it important that mathematicians--especially "newbies"--learn that powerful software is available to solve such problems, and they would do well to learn it for the larger problems that they must solve in a future career involving mathematics.

Anyway, in full detail (*Mathematica*):

```
eq1 = (y /. Solve[a x + b y == 1, y][[1]])
```

$$\frac{1 - a x}{b}$$

```
eq2 = (y /. Solve[c x + d y == 2, y][[1]])
```

$$\frac{2 - c x}{d}$$

```
Solve[eq1 == eq2, x][[1]]
```

$$\{x \to \frac{2 b - d}{b c - a d} \}$$

Comment: Hello, David, and thanks for your response! I will definitely look into it in the future as I heard about Mathematica's power before but this time I actually had the answer from the textbook but didn't know how to get there.